# Click on submit button after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #ddd; float: left;"></div>
<div id="list" style="width: 200px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ddd; float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
    <div class="section">
        Ja/Nej
        <div class="showforms" style="display: none;">
            <strong>Fritext</strong>
            <input type="text" name="question">
            <p><input type="radio" name="test" value=1> Ja<br>
            <input type="radio" name="test" value=0> Nej<br></p>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Spara" class="save">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Option list
        <div class="showforms" style="display: none">
            <select>
                <option>Fisk</option>
                <option>Fisk2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonObj = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('.section').draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        stack: ".yesorno",
        helper: "clone"
    });
        
    $('#main').droppable({
        accept: ".section",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                
            //Lagra ui-objektet i en lista
            //Loopa ut objekten och sätt ett index på varje classnamn och visa input fältet
                
            jsonObj[i] = {"Objekt": ui.draggable, "Id": i};
            var draggable = jsonObj[i]["Objekt"];
            var droppable = $(this);
            draggable.show('.showforms');
            draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
                
            $("#main").find("div").attr('id', i).show();
            var testa = $('#main').find("div")[i];
            var submit = $(testa).find(":submit").attr('test', i);
            console.log($(testa).find(":submit"));
            //Object[div#yesorno.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle]          
            i++;
        }
    });
});
    
$('.save').click(function() {
    console.log("hej"); //This don't work
});
```

The thing I'm doing here is that I take a section-div containing some input-fields that is being hidden. I drag this into the main-div and drop it here. After it has been dropped, the input-fields are shown.

The problem I have is that nothing is printed out when I click on the submit button after I have dragged and dropped it in the Main-div. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example here on a website like https://jsfiddle.net/grkftm5s/ so we can better help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved It by doing this:

```
    $(document).on('click', ".save", function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('test'));       
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:
Replace

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Spara" class="save">
```

With

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Spara" class="save" onClick="saveFunction()">
```

Replace

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    console.log("hej"); //This don't work
}
```

With

```
function saveFunction(){
    console.log("hej");
}
```

Comment: why you think `<input type="submit" name="save" value="Spara" class="save">` & `$('.save').click(function() {
    console.log("hej"); //This don't work
}` will not work ?